# Incremental Saves

Tags: python, save, maya

I am trying to write up a script on incremental saves but there are a few hiccups that I am running into.

If the file name is "aaa.ma", I will get the following error - `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'aaa' #` and it does not happens if my file is named "aaa_0001"

And this happens if I wrote my code in this format: [Link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=W3x6YF40)

As such, to rectify the above problem, I input in an `if..else..` statement - [Link](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=vCL0aCLn), it seems to have resolved the issue on hand, but I was wondering if there is a better approach to this?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A bit offtopic on your current problem. But I had to write a similar script for our studio a year ago. But here are some feedback I could give you. 1) be sure to get a result from this command : `cmds.file(query = True, sceneName=True)` sometimes it doesn't return any filepath at our office. 2) Check if the file doesn't already exist before saving
3) We ended up using a naming library to help us check file path and conformity. We used this one as a base [link](https://pythonhosted.org/kabaret/naming.html) and modified it to our own needs.

Comment: @DrHaze Thanks for providing me a few pointers, especially Point #1.. So far that code seems to be working in my cause, but I shall double check again. The file-checking does makes sense too now that you mentioned it. Will try to integrate it and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regexes for better flexibility especially for file rename scripts like these.

In your case, since you know that the expected filename format is `"some_file_name_<increment_number>"`, you can use regexes to do the searching and matching for you. The reason we should do this is because people/users may are not machines, and may not stick to the exact naming conventions that our scripts expect. For example, the user may name the file `aaa_01.ma` or even `aaa001.ma` instead of `aaa_0001` that your script currently expects. To build this flexibility into your script, you can use regexes. For your use case, you could do:

```
# name = lastIncFile.partition(".")[0] # Use os.path.split instead
name, ext = os.path.splitext(lastIncFile)

import re

match_object = re.search("([a-zA-Z]*)_*([0-9]*)$", name)
# Here ([a-zA-Z]*) would be group(1) and would have "aaa" for ex.
# and ([0-9]*) would be group(2) and would have "0001" for ex.
# _* indicates that there may be an _, or not.
# The $ indicates that ([0-9]*) would be the LAST part of the name.

padding = 4  # Try and parameterize as many components as possible for easy maintenance 
default_starting = 1
verName = str(default_starting).zfill(padding)  # Default verName
if match_object: # True if the version string was found
    name = match_object.group(1)
    version_component = match_object.group(2)
    if version_component:
        verName = str(int(version_component) + 1).zfill(padding)

newFileName = "%s_%s.%s" % (name, verName, ext)
incSaveFilePath = os.path.join(curFileDir, newFileName)
```

Check out this nice [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) on Python regexes to get an idea what is going on in the above block. Feel free to tweak, evolve and build the regex based on your use cases, tests and needs.

#### Extra tips:

Call `cmds.file(renameToSave=True)` at the beginning of the script. This will ensure that the file does not get saved over itself accidentally, and forces the script/user to rename the current file. Just a safety measure.

If you want to go a little fancy with your regex expression and make them more readable, you could try doing this:

```
match_object = re.search("(?P<name>[a-zA-Z]*)_*(?P<version>[0-9]*)$", name)
name = match_object.group('name')
version_component = match_object('version')
```

Here we use the `?P<var_name>...` syntax to assign a dict key name to the matching group. Makes for better readability when you access it - `mo.group('version')` is much more clearer than `mo.group(2)`.
Make sure to go through the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) too.

Save using Maya's commands. This will ensure Maya does all it's checks while and before saving:

```
cmds.file(rename=incSaveFilePath)
cmds.file(save=True)
```

#### Update-2:

If you want space to be checked here's an updated regex:

```
match_object = re.search("(?P<name>[a-zA-Z]*)[_ ]*(?P<version>[0-9]*)$", name)
```

Here `[_ ]*` will check for 0 - many occurrences of `_` or (space). For more regex stuff, trying and learn on your own is the best way. Check out the links on this post.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I haven't got the chance to test the code you have provided but was wondering for the regex search, will it be possible to search for either `_` or spaces, in the event if the file is named as `aaa 001`?